# 32bit Internet Explorer on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, internet-explorer, 32-bit

Is there a way to install 32bit version of Internet Explorer (AFAIK doesn't matter which version) on 64bit Windows 10?

There already is Internet Explorer in Windows 10 but it seems there's only a 64bit version.

I've tried to install the 32bit version for Windows 7 SP1 downloaded from microsoft.com website without success even with the compatibility mode on (right click on the installation file -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Win 7 SP1).

I would prefer a solution without the need to install virtual machine if possible.

I've seen [this page](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/) offering "ready made" virtual machines of various versions of IE but it's only for testing purposes and they say it works just for 90 days.

And yes, I really need to install 32bit IE because there's a crucial web application which is not compatible with other browsers nor other versions of IE.

Comment: the 32Bit version is buildin in Win10

Comment: @magicandre1981 When I run iexplore.exe from Program Files(x86) it doesn't append (32) to the processes's name in Task manager. Or how else can I tell if it's the 32bit version?

Comment: the main IE is 64Bit, but the child processes which host the tabs run as 32Bit